# Error: Named bind parameter "$_0dj" has no value in the given object

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize version 6.0.0 , I am facing issues when creating models ,values are note binding correctly
I am always getting below error:

> Error: Named bind parameter "$_0dj" has no value in the given object.

Here is my code:

```
    Information = sequelize.define('information', {
        id:{
            field: 'id',
            type : Sequelize.INTEGER ,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title:{
            field:"title",
            type:Sequelize.BLOB,
            allowNull:false     
        },
        description:{
            field:"description",
            type:Sequelize.BLOB,
            allowNull:false  
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'information',
        schema:'mdi'
    });

Information.create({
         title:Sequelize.fn('AES_ENCRYPT',req.body.title,'123456789'),
         description: Sequelize.fn('AES_ENCRYPT',req.body.description,       '123456789')
        })
        .then(function(){
        } );
    });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm seeing a similar problem.

Comment: So, after some investigation, I'm guessing your problem is your `req.body.*` has `$` in it. I've filed a bug with Sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11533

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue.

In my case, I had the encryption key stored in a variable. The encryption key contained the `$` character:

```
Sequelize.fn('AES_ENCRYPT', value, encryptKey)
```

You have to pass the variable content with `sequelize.literal` like so:

```
Sequelize.fn('AES_ENCRYPT', value, sequelize.literal(`'${encryptKey}'`))
```

Got this from [a thread](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11533#issuecomment-796464734) in sequelize's known issues.